# Sonarscanner on Jenkins: Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, java-11, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to run the .net core sonarscanner tool on Jenkins (running on Linux) like:

`dotnet sonarscanner begin ...`

But it's giving the error

`Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH.`

I'm not sure why this is as I am explicitly setting the path at the top of my pipeline:

```
environment {
    JAVA_HOME="${tool 'openjdk-11'}/jdk-11"
    PATH="${tool 'openjdk-11'}/jdk-11/bin:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/:$PATH" 
}
```

And from running the following commands I can see this looks correct:

`sh "echo \"Java Home:\" $JAVA_HOME"`

Produces:

`Java Home: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-11`

And listing the directory:

`sh "ls /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-11/jdk-11/bin"`

produces:

```
+ ls /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-11/jdk-11/bin
jaotc
jar
jarsigner
java
javac
javadoc
javap
jcmd
jconsole
jdb
jdeprscan
jdeps
jhsdb
jimage
jinfo
jjs
jlink
jmap
jmod
jps
jrunscript
jshell
jstack
jstat
jstatd
keytool
pack200
rmic
rmid
rmiregistry
serialver
unpack200
```

Yet still, sonar scanner fails with the error:

`Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH.`

**UPDATE:**

Regarding Dimitry's comment - I am using the tools:

[image: tools]

With this at the top of the pipeline:

```
  tools{
      jdk 'openjdk-11'
  }
```

With regards to Marcinek's answer - good spot. I've realised that setting the JAVA_HOME at the top of the pipeline is not actually doing anything. Whatever I set it to, it remains as:

`/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-11`

Comment: There should be a jenkins configuration where Java is supposed to be. See here: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking_and_servers/9781788297943/1/ch01lvl1sec20/configuring-java-home-in-jenkins
Because there can be multiple java installations.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @JeromyFrench you probably solved this ages ago, but for anyone else running into the same issue: Sonarqube is shipped with its own JRE, and execution of the java executable in there must be permitted using `chmod` first. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62587660/808151

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$JAVA_HOME` should point to the main directory of java, where the bin folder can be found by appending `bin`

Your `$JAVA_HOME` variable is pointing to

```
Java Home: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-11
```

To find the java executable you have to append `jdk-11/bin`

Thus the correct path to JAVA_HOME should be:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-11/jdk-11
```

And the PATH should point to:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-11/jdk-11/bin
```

Comment: Good spot. I've updated my question - I can't seem to change the JAVA_HOME variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'tools' section to use java in your pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        jdk 'your-jdk-tool-name' 
    }
```

Comment: Yep - that's what I'm doing